# what does $_ (ruby underscore) global method return?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What does the global variable `$_` return in ruby?

Is it just echoing the response of the previously called method, or is it returning (raw) last line of code read by the interpreter?

[Here](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/globalvars.html) it says:

> string last read by gets

and in `builtin.rb` it says:

```
# Last line read by Kernel#gets or Kernel#readline.
# This variable is defined in current scope, thread local.
$_ = "" #value is unknown, used for indexing.
```

This is what I get in the console:

```
[1] pry(main)> x = 1 + 5
=> 6
[2] pry(main)> _
=> 6
[3] pry(main)> y = 3 + 3
=> 6
[4] pry(main)> $_
=> nil
```

What is the difference between `_` and `$_` ?

---

here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jefflab/566464#file-builtin-rb-L134) with builtin.rb that someone has created...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_` is the last string read from `IO` by one of `Kernel.gets`, `Kernel.readline` or siblings.

Pry introduces the underscore variable, returning the result of the last operation, on its own. It has nothing to do with ruby globals.

Comment: IRB does the same.